# When i create a trigger it gives an error saying it is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: plsql, triggers

I tried updating the client_master table but It gave an error Idk why.I did update client_master set name='abc' where name='xyz';

```
  create or replace trigger client_audit before update or delete on client_master for each row
begin
    case 
        when updating then
            insert into audit_client values(:OLD.c_no,:OLD.name,:OLD.address,:OLD.bal_due,'upd','1',sysdate);
        when deleting then
            insert into audit_client values(:OLD.c_no,:OLD.name,:OLD.address,:OLD.bal_due,'delet','2',sysdate);
    end case;
end;
/
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score -1):

Try this solution. Hope this helps.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER client_audit before
  UPDATE OR
  DELETE ON client_master FOR EACH row 
  DECLARE
  BEGIN 
  IF UPDATING THEN
  INSERT
  INTO audit_client VALUES
    (
      :OLD.c_no,
      :OLD.name,
      :OLD.address,
      :OLD.bal_due,
      'upd',
      '1',
      sysdate
    );
ELSIF DELETING THEN
  INSERT
  INTO audit_client VALUES
    (
      :OLD.c_no,
      :OLD.name,
      :OLD.address,
      :OLD.bal_due,
      'delet',
      '2',
      sysdate
    );
END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: If you think this answers the question, you should explain your reasoning. i.e. do you think there's something wrong with the `case` statement?